# How to establish a many to one relationship between 2 tables for a field

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key, many-to-one

I am building an database schema for a project and I am bit stuck on this issue. I have 2 tables:

USER table:

```
Id  Name    Contact_ID
1   Arun    2
2   Barath  3
3   Charan  2
4   Dinesh  1
```

CONTACT table:

```
ID  Name    Phone   Mail
1   Mahesh  1234    Mahesh@Yahoo.com
2   Suresh  54321   Sureh@Google.com
3   Jayesh  9876    Jayesh@Bing.com
4   Ganesh  98754   Gahesh@Safari.com
```

Each of the users in USER will have a contact in CONTACT.
If a user has a single contact then I can use a foreign key relationship on Contact_ID in USER and build the relationship between them.

But what if an user in the USER table has multiple contacts in the CONTACT table? I am not sure how to build the relationship between them.

Eg:
In USER for user Charan there is one contact, contact 2, but what if there is one more, contact 4?
In that case how can I build the many to one relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got it backwards. Your CONTACT table should have a foreign key reference to USER table, rather than USER containing a foreign key reference to CONTACT. For example:

USER table

```
Id  Name 
1   Arun  
2   Barath 
3   Charan 
4   Dinesh
```

CONTACT table

```
ID  Name    Phone   Mail                USER_ID
1   Mahesh  1234    Mahesh@Yahoo.com    1
2   Suresh  54321   Sureh@Google.com    2
3   Jayesh  9876    Jayesh@Bing.com     1
4   Ganesh  98754   Gahesh@Safari.com   3
```

Of course, I just used fake data for the new USER_ID column. As you can see, USER with Id 1 (Arun) has multiple contacts (IDs 1 and 3) in the CONTACT table.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In the relational model (and ER model) *tables* represent (business/application) *relationships/associations*. FKs (foreign keys) are *called* "relationships" by pseudo-relational (& pseudo-ER) methods.

```
-- user "id" has name "name" and ...
user(id, name, ...)
-- contact "id" has name "name" and ...
contact(id, name, ...)
-- user "uid" has contact "cid"
user_has_contact(uid, cid)
```

If `user_has_contact` is N:1 in `uid`:`cid` then you can replace `user` & `user_has_contact` by:

```
--    user "id" has ... AND user "id" has contact "cid"
user(id, name, ..., cid)
```

If `user_has_contact` is 1:N in `uid`:`cid` then you can replace `contact` & `user_has_contact` by:

```
--    contact "id" has ... AND user "uid" has contact "id"
contact(id, name, ..., uid)
```

You should use the first design for M:M. (You don't actually *have* to but then the joined tables exhibit problems that normalization would tell you to solve by having the separate tables.) This is called an association/junction/join/many-to-many/bridge table in methods that call FKs "relationships". But like every table it represents a relationship/association on some values. (And hence also any identified entities.) It also handles M:0-or-1 & 0-or-1:M . The other two designs can do that too using `NULL`.

Regardless of the cardinality of `user_has_contact` it is probably a good idea to keep the three separate because it is straightforward. (True ER modeling would give the two entity tables & one association table.) But you should realize that there is no *need* to join them.

A FK tells the DBMS that values for a list of columns in a table must appear as a CK (candidate key) elsewhere. (In SQL, a FK says they appear as a superkey, ie SQL PK (primary key) or UNIQUE NOT NULL, elsewhere.)

(Methods that call FKs "relationships" do so because FKs are associated with relationships like `user_has_contact` that have be joined into what becomes the referencing table. Also it is those relationships' cardinalities that are called the FKs' cardinalities. But a FK constraint just states a fact; it isn't a relationship/association.)

You need to find & follow references for information modeling & database design.